# If in a situation, conservative and non-conservative forces act, what’s the general way to find work done by an individual force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, work

Let’s say we are solving a problem involving a vertical spring. I know that we can solve it by neglecting gravity completely and solely concentrating on the spring force.

So let’s assume,with the above ideology in mind,that a person slides on a rough slide.

Or any other situation where force due to gravity and friction are involved,so, in these cases too can I neglect work done by gravity or by friction to calculate work done by the other force?

To clarify, I know that if friction works then either the person comes to rest after he slides down the slide/incline or slows down in velocity, how to find work done by a force in these two cases(if specifics were required for this question)

Comment: when you say "acquires a velocity" do you mean that the person's velocity changes?

Comment: Yeah thought what else could it mean:)?

Answer (score 0):

We don't necessarily need to neglect work done by the other forces. We can just solely calculate the work done by the specific force in question.

With the formula $$W = \int Fdx$$ we can just focus on the specific force and see for how much of a distance this force does work on. For example, on your "person on a slide" situation, first find the force of friction (which is most likely $$f = -mg\cos\theta \mu_k$$ and if we know that this force acts on say, a length $D$ on the slide, then the work done is just $$|W| = f\cdot D = mg\cos\theta\mu_k D$$ and we are done.

Comment: @DilinFinn 
does this answer your question?